# Search inside word docs and across other websites

Tags: lucene.net, orchardcms

Is there a way to configure lucene.net in Orchard to search the content of word docs in a dir under the Orchard root. And is there a way to have it index another website as well.

Comment: Lucene.Net is neither *a content analysis toolkit* nor a *web crawler*.  Get the text *somehow* and index it using Lucene.Net

Answer (score 0):

If you can somehow add the content as contentitems in Orchard, you can use a trick with the `OnIndexing` method inside a `ContentHandler`.

Something like this should do it:

```
public class WordDocumentContentHandler: ContentHandler {
    public WordDocumentContentHandler() {
        OnIndexing<ContentPart>((context, part) => {
            // Detect if the part has the field containing the URL to the document
            // and analyze it here. 
        });
    }
}
```